# Access-denied, changing the user (admin) restriction in 3rd party module controller to allow non-admin user access

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, acl

In a 3rd party module that we have, the controllers for routes are configured with `<use>admin</use>`. So then it extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` and adding `function _isAllowed()` does not solves the access denied for non-admin user. would removing `<use>admin</use>` be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow non-admin access, the controller MUST NOT extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`.

You would also need to change `<use>admin</use>` from "admin" to "default".

But depending on what the controller does, it might not work outside the admin area, you have to try it out.

Comment: Thanks I'll try your suggestions tonight and keep here updated

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. Changing admin to default leads to 404 page and removing the extending part leads to a blank page :(

Comment: The blank page is a PHP fatal error, that means the controller does things that only work in admin area, as I suspected. That could be using the admin session or changing entities that are read only in frontend. At this point I can only guess. If you inspect the server error logs and find the code responsible for the error, you should be able to find out (or ask a new question with these details)